# Avoiding missed events from services during configuration/orientation changes

Tags: android, events, service, long-running-processes

I'm trying to figure out proper/recommended approaches avoiding missed events from a long-running service during a configuration change. For example, I need to avoid a situation where an Activity misses a task completion event when the device is rotated, causing a progress spinner to stay visible.

I'm currently handling this by creating a view-less retained `Fragment`,  named `EventCollector`, that contains a `BroadcastReceiver` which receives broadcasts from the service. An Activity, or any other class that wants to receive these events, implements `EventCollectorListener` and calls `EventCollector.attachListener(TAG, this)` to register and `EventCollector.detachListener(TAG)` to unregister for receiving events. When detached, events are stored in a queue until `attachListener()` is called again. (Implementation is available at [1] and example at [2]).

A normal flow of events would be something like the following:

1. Activity is started.
2. Activity attaches itself by calling `EventCollector.attachListener()` in `onResume()`.
3. Activity handles events from the `onEventReceived()` method of the `EventCollectorListener` interface.
4. User rotates device.
5. Activity detaches itself by calling `EventCollector.detachListener()` in `onPause()` before it gets destroyed.
6. Events received during this time from the service are queued in the `EventCollector` instance.
7. Activity is recreated and calls `EventCollector.attachListener()` in `onResume()` again, at which point, all queued events are sent.

This has some disadvantages, like how every single event between `onPause()` and `onResume()` is cached. If my service is extracting a zip archive, for example, there is no point keeping progress events for 1%, 2%, etc, if the process is already 80% done. Also, if the Activity is purposely destroyed (eg. back button), events will continue piling up in the queue.

I feel like my solution is very hacky and it seems like I'm working against the way Android is supposed to work. I've not seen anybody use a solution like this and I assume this is a fairly common use case, so are there better ways to avoid missed events from services? Am I totally wrong in my approach of handling long-running tasks by using `IntentService`s and intents/broadcasts for communication? Should I be using a bound service instead and if so, how would the general structure look like?

I don't mind making drastic changes to implement a better solution.

Thanks in advance! Any feedback is appreciated.

---

References:

1. https://github.com/chenxiaolong/DualBootPatcher/blob/47f13965adf4793fea784b736475fa912f7c8d27/Android_GUI/src/com/github/chenxiaolong/dualbootpatcher/EventCollector.java
2. https://github.com/chenxiaolong/DualBootPatcher/blob/47f13965adf4793fea784b736475fa912f7c8d27/Android_GUI/src/com/github/chenxiaolong/dualbootpatcher/switcher/SwitcherEventCollector.java